# Any way to distribute unsigned IOS apps on non-jailbroken devices?

Tags: ios, installation, unsigned

Is there any way to distribute in-house IOS APPs to our employees without signing them (non-jailbroken devices)?

Citrix offers mobile device management software with their receiver - could using a system similar to this allow us to get around the signature requirement for IOS Apps?  (any open source solutions?)

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you logged into iTunes Connect lately?

> TestFlight Beta Testing for External Testers
>
> You can now invite up to 1000 users to test prerelease builds of your
>   app. To do so, go to External Testers in Prerelease for the app that
>   you want to test and add external testers simply by sending an email
>   invitation. The TestFlight app will allow them to install the
>   prerelease build on their iOS device, receive updates, and provide
>   feedback, all within the TestFlight app.